# How to import a new library from GitHub (android studio)

Tags: android, github, android-studio

I download with android studio a library from GitHub(https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary#howtouse)
but I dont know how to import it into my project.
I tried to do what shown there bud I didn't succeed...
I looked for tutorial  at a least for hour-but I didnt find anything usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page covers what you need to do really well. But with pictures :

You click on build.gradle file

[image]

And you add relevant line into repositories and dependencies

[image]

In your case you add

```
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
```

as a new line . (You can see some support libraries already there, like I do)

Comment: Thanks, it's what I already did- but then I tried to add Flat Button code(http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=1tygokue31mt.png)  I have this situation: http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=wtg1cinz5yyt.png                                      and sometimes the button display but it's just have his shape withuot background color(although in the setting the color is setup aouto). what shuld I do?

Comment: should flat button have background anyway? I'm not really familiar with this library, you should try asking author sorry

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you solve the issue - it also removes it from 'unanswered' queue